# Object pass by reference in a fuction

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to change an object value in one function with another but the value remains the same. Sorry for the bad coding, I'm still a noob.

```
void fun2(sampleObject &test){

     sampleObject &temp = test;

     //I called the setter to change the value of the first int.
     temp.setFirst(temp.getFirst() - 2);

     //Doesn't work with test.setFirst(test.getFirst() - 2);
}


void  fun1(){

     /*sampleObject is a class that was created.
       with a constructor of (int, int, string);
     */
     sampleObject test[1];

     test[0] = {100, 30, "Hello"};

     //fun2 should change the first int value.
     fun2(test[0]);

     cout << "First number in test 0 is " << test[0].getFirst();
     //Prints 100 instead of 98.

}

int main(){
     fun1();
     return 0;
 }
 //No luck.
```

Comment: The code is somehow confusing. Is fun1 a function? Is Event derived from sampleObject? Please provide detailed Infos.

Comment: Please post a more understandable code.

Comment: The code do not make any sense!!!

Comment: Super confusing code ! Please clarify what `sampleObject` and `Event` etc are?

Comment: The code has updated!.

Answer (score 0):

replace your object and use this format to change the value of your array by ref

```
void func2(int &test){
    int &temp = test;
    temp = temp-2;
}

void func1(){
    int test[1];
    test[0] = 100;
    func2(test[0]);
    cout << test[0];
}

int main() {
    func1(); //Print 98

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know that will work for an int as the parameter but the object that I have created from sampleObject, it didn't change the value of the first int.